# Why I cannot write anything in the console after the start of local server?

Tags: laravel

As soon as I start Laravel Development by typing `php artisan serve`, it starts my local server. But after that, I cannot write anything on the console. If I restart cmd or use `ctrl + c`, then it stops the server from working.

So after using the command `php artisan serve`, it does not allow me to write anything using the command line. What could I do to avoid this, because I can't proceed further using the console?

Comment: Add & sign in the end, it will keep your server running in the background and you can work on console.

Comment: or you can start another console with this running console

Comment: You mean this- `php artisan serve&` ?

Comment: Give space before &

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run this process in the background by putting `&` sign at the end.

```
php artisan serve &
```

Note that when using `&` closing the terminal will terminate the application. If you want to keep your process running after closing console add `disown` after `&`, so you new command will look like this:

On Linux/macOS:

```
php artisan serve & disown
```

On Windows:

```
START /B php artisan serve
```

Comment: What is the benefit of adding &, if I could not close the terminal, and I have tried `php artisan serve &`, it's still not allowing me to write any thing on the console?

Comment: This command is also not working. Neither I can type anything on the console after srarting server nor I can access the server after closing the console.

Comment: What operating system you are using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Comment: START /B php artisan serve

Answer (score 3):

1-you can start another Console

2-you can use any php server like wamp or xampp i prefer wamp